# What is the node-gyp standard PATH on Windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, node-modules, node-gyp

I edit my PATH of node-gyp and cannot return it back to normal. So if I type

```
 node-gyp -v
```

it opens a `node-gyp.js` file itself.

How should I change my `PATH` of node-gyp to return it back to normal?

Answer (score 2):

You can install with npm [read me](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/master/README.md):

```
$ npm install -g node-gyp
```

You will also need to install:

On Windows:

Python (v2.7.10 recommended, v3.x.x is not supported)

Make sure that you have a PYTHON environment variable, and it is set to drive:\path\to\python.exe not to a folder

Windows XP/Vista/7:

Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2013 (Express version works well)

- If the install fails, try uninstalling any C++ 2010 x64&x86 Redistributable that you have installed first
- If you get errors that the 64-bit compilers are not installed you may also need the compiler update for the Windows SDK 7.1

Windows 7/8:

Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2013 for Windows Desktop (Express version works well)

Windows 10:

- Install the latest version of npm (3.3.6 at the time of writing)
- Install Python 2.7 from https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/ and make sure its on the System Path
- Install Visual Studio Community 2015 Edition. (Custom Install, Select Visual C++ during the installation)
- Set the environment variable GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2015
- Run the command prompt as Administrator
- $ npm install (--msvs_version=2015) <-- Shouldn't be needed if you have set GYP_MSVS_VERSION env
- If the above steps have not worked or you are unsure please visit http://www.serverpals.com/blog/building-using-node-gyp-with-visual-studio-express-2015-on-windows-10-pro-x64 for a full walkthrough

All Windows Versions

For 64-bit builds of node and native modules you will also need the [Windows 7 64-bit SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279)

You may need to run one of the following commands if your build complains about WindowsSDKDir not being set, and you are sure you have already installed the SDK:

```
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\bin\Setenv.cmd" /Release /x86
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\bin\Setenv.cmd" /Release /x64
```

If you have multiple Python versions installed, you can identify which Python version node-gyp uses by setting the '--python' variable:

```
$ node-gyp --python /path/to/python2.7
```

If node-gyp is called by way of npm and you have multiple versions of Python installed, then you can set npm's 'python' config key to the appropriate value:

```
$ npm config set python /path/to/executable/python2.7
```

As a reminder, you should include the entire folder that contains the module as a path to Windows.
Add an environment variable called NODE_PATH and set it to %USERPROFILE%\Application Data\npm\node_modules (Windows XP), %AppData%\npm\node_modules (Windows 7/8/10), or wherever npm ends up installing the modules on your Windows flavor. To be done with it once and for all, add this as a System variable in the Advanced tab of the System Properties dialog (run control.exe sysdm.cpl,System,3).

Quick solution in Windows 7+ is to just run:

```
rem for future
setx NODE_PATH %AppData%\npm\node_modules
rem for current session
set NODE_PATH=%AppData%\npm\node_modules
```

It's worth to mention that NODE_PATH is only used when importing modules in Node apps. When you want to use globally installed modules' binaries in your CLI you need to add it also to your PATH, but without node_modules part (for example %AppData%\npm in Windows 7/8/10).